# Saab 9-5 (2006) engine lamp on - a loose hose found under the hood

Tags: automatic-transmission, troubleshooting, saab, vacuum-leak, vacuum-hoses

When I start the engine of a Saab 9-5 (2006), the engine lamp is always on.
I am not sure but I found two loose hoses. One of them I connected as shown in the image below.
[image]
Could someone confirm that I did the right thing here?

Then I found another loose hose, which is shown in the image below.
[image]
But I could not easily locate the place where it should be connected (if it should be connected at all). Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think it is specific enough. Engine lamp is on, two loose hoses. Are they supposed to be loose? Is the first hose connected right?